# limit the maximum amount of memory sqlite3 uses

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using sqlite3 in python, the program runns in different threads. Sqlite3 resides only in one thread. After a while the sqlite3 thread takes ot much memory.

How can I limit the maximum amount of memory sqlite3 uses?

What are rules of tumb about the maximal memory size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in PRAGMA statements to a cursor objects to change the behavior of the database for the current session.

> The PRAGMA statement is issued using the same interface as other SQLite commands (e.g. SELECT, INSERT)

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect(FILENAME)
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> cur.execute("PRAGMA cache_size = -512") # Negative value means use N * 1024 bytes of memory.
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x01F14260>
```

From the SQLite Docs: http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_cache_size

Comment: Granted this example uses a ridiculously small amount of memory, but it is only for illustration purposes.

Comment: It makes no sense to limit the cache size in a :memory: database. Maybe you could adapt your example

Comment: Why is 512 megabites a small amount of cache?

Comment: @DavoudTaghawi-Nejad, You are right but I didn't choose to use an arbitrary db name. The example still stands. Its not 512MB, but rather 512KB. (1024 bytes == 1 KB)

Comment: conn = sqlite3.connect(FILENAME) would be correct and more clear